# why can I not extract the line item from the token

Tags: commerce, tokens

I have an online store and would like to extract the purchased line item at check out for further processing in `php`. Now, I have enabeled  tokens in my `PGP Code` text format and have moved processing of the tokens before the `PHP evaluator`.  i have run a test with the order number in my checkout message and it works fine with it but for some reason, it does not let me interpret, print or process the line item token:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!<br>";
echo "[commerce-order:commerce_line_items]";
echo "Order number: [commerce-order:order-number]<br/>---------------<br/>";
?>
```

Doesn't print anything on checkout, however

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!<br>";
echo "Order number: [commerce-order:order-number]<br/>---------------<br/>";
?>
```

prints the order number as expected and moving the `[commerce-order:commerce_line_items]` outside the `<?php` brackets works as expected too. I'm perplexed, what am I possibly missing?

Thanks for any support with this!

Comment: Where is the email text located at? In code or in the admin?

Comment: There are other similar issues posted on Drupal.org https://www.drupal.org/node/1333174#comment-5834418 and https://www.drupal.org/node/1300678 describe this and may help.

Comment: @burnsjeremy"email text" , I don't know what "email text" you are referring to. There is no email part of that at all, I want to use tokens from commerce in the commerce `Completion message` on checkout to refer to the just completed order.